# Publish WPF project as .exe file

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, visual-studio

I have several project in which I need to send arguments to, my problem is I cannot send arguments to `‏‏‫Application Reference‬ (‪.appref-ms‬)`.

Is there a way to publish projects as `.exe` file and not `‏‏‫Application Reference‬ (‪.appref-ms‬)`?

Comment: Build the application and copy the contents of the `bin\Debug` or `bin\Release` folder in the project directory to the target machine? The output folder will contain the .exe and all dependencies.

Comment: This is what I'm doing now, but there is a good way of doing this other then copying every time?

Comment: Every time? Of course you need to build and copy everytime you want to deploy a new version. Or what do you mean?

Comment: I mean if there is a way when I click publish, it will publish `exe` file and not `Application Reference‬ (‪.appref-ms‬)`.
I wrote a method to check if the files are up-to-date, but it seams to me like there is a build in way to do so with visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

After you publish your program, check the Application Files, there's a ".exe" file.

Just remove ".deploy" or change your settings to remove ".deploy" after you publish.

Publish > Options > Deployment > uncheck the  "use .deployment file extension"

Comment: I unchecked the field, and published it, but yet the installer installed `Application Reference‬ (‪.appref-ms‬)` file.